# NSRoundBankers is not working as documented by Apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, nsdecimalnumber

So, according to Apple's documentation about **NSRoundBankers**:

*Round to the closest possible return value; when halfway between two possibilities, return the possibility whose last digit is even.*

While this is true for positive numbers, **I am not getting the expected behaviour on negative numbers**. Here is the piece of code I executed on the device and on the simulator, both printing the exact same results:

```
NSDecimalNumber *increment = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:5 exponent:-2 isNegative:NO];
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:10 exponent:-1 isNegative:YES];
NSDecimalNumberHandler *handler = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundBankers scale:1 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];
while ([number compare:@1] == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSLog(@";%@;%@", number, [number decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:handler]);
    number = [number decimalNumberByAdding:increment];
}
```

On negative numbers, it's not returning the one whose last digit is even, it basically rounds down.

For example, for **-0.85** i should be getting **-0.8**, but I am getting **-0.9**

**Am I doing something wrong?**

Left table shows the ACTUAL behaviour, in red marked the wrong rounded values.

Right table shows the EXPECTED behaviour, in green the correct rounded values.

[image: iOS]
[image: Java]

Comment: it happened only for -0.85....have you tried for other numbers too?

Comment: Yeah you can see in the table -0.65 should be -0.6 but it's -0.7
same thing with -0.45, -0.25, -0.05.....

Comment: have you tried nsroundplain? If that doesn't workout too....then report it to apple!!!

Comment: We need to have the same behaviour on Backend and Clients, so I can't really choose a different rounding method. :/

Comment: In the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSRoundingMode Apple shows an example of NSRoundBankers rounding -1.35 to -1.4, so that does appear to be the designed behavior.

Comment: -1.35 rounding to -1.4 makes sense (digit 4 is an even number)

-1.45 rounding to -1.5 does not make sense (digit 5 is an odd number)

-1.45 should be rounded to -1.4

Comment: I ran into the same problem using Swift and ended up here.  Sadly, no one has answered this question

Comment: I did discover that the Swift class NumberFormatter DOES handle .roundHalfEven correctly.  It can be used to round negative numbers correctly.  Unfortunately, you have to convert the number to a String and then back to a number.  Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this today and it's probably a bug in Foundation. If the source code of swift-corelibs-foundation has anything to do with the actual Foundation code, I might have found the culprit: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/70f8af962ff182c78a81673e75fe725b5b1b7827/Foundation/Decimal.swift#L1970.

I believe 1 should be *subtracted* from remainder on the line 1970, not added to it. Rationale: if remainder is 5, what does adding 1 to it actually change? The case falls trough (line 1972) and the check on line 1974 succeeds either way, be it 5 or 6. If it were to become 4 for after subtracting, it will prevent adding 1 to `self` (line 1979) and keep the number even.

**UPD** the issue has been reported to Apple: FB7565793.

**UPD 2** the issue has been fixed by Apple in the first betas of iOS 14 / macOS 11.0.

Comment: I'm amazed this is still relevant, and happening, after 4.5 years. :D
GJ in digging in the code and reporting a possible bug 

Comment: Update: the issue has been fixed by Apple in the first betas of iOS 14 / macOS 11.0.